# Q) Write a query to return Territory and corresponding Sales Growth (compare growth between periods Q4-2019 vs Q3-2019)

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

Q) Write a query to return Territory and corresponding Sales Growth (compare growth between periods Q4-2019 vs Q3-2019).

Tables given-

```
Cust_Sales: -Cust_id,product_sku,order_date,order_value,order_id,month
Cust_Territory: cust_id,territory_id,customer_city,customer_pincode
```

Use tables FCT_CUSTOMER_SALES (which has sales for each Customer) and MAP_CUSTOMER_TERRITORY (which provides Territory-to-Customer mapping) for this question.

```
Output format-
TERRITORY_ID | SALES_GROWTH
```

My solution-

```
Select ((q2.claims - q1.claims)/q1.claims * 100) AS SALES_GROWTH , c.territory_id

From

(select sum(s.order_value) from FCT_CUSTOMER_SALES s inner join MAP_CUSTOMER_TERRITORY c on s.customer_id=c.customer_id where s.order_datetime between 1/07/2019 and 30/09/2019 group by c.territory_id) as q1.claims,

(select sum(s.order_value) from FCT_CUSTOMER_SALES s inner join MAP_CUSTOMER_TERRITORY c on s.customer_id=c.customer_id where s.order_datetime between 1/10/2019 and 31/12/2019 group by c.territory_id) as q2.claims

Group by c.territory_id
```

My solution is showing up as incorrect I would request anyone who can help me out with the solution and let me know where my mistake is

Answer (score 0):

One option uses conditional aggregation. The idea is to filter the table on the two quarters at once, then use `case` expressions within the `sum()` aggregate function to compute the sales of each of them:

```
select 
    c.territory_id,
    ( sum(case when s.order_date >= date '2020-01-01' then s.order_value end) 
        - sum(case when s.order_date < date '2020-01-01' then s.order_value end)
    ) / (sum(case when s.order_date < date '2020-01-01' then s.order_value end)) * 100.0 as sales_growth
from fct_customer_sales s 
inner join map_customer_territory c on s.customer_id = c.customer_id 
where s.order_datetime >= date '2020-01-07' and s.order_datetime < '2020-01-01'
group by c.territory_id
```

You did not tell which database you are using, while date features are highly vendor-dependent. This uses the standard `DATE` syntax to declare the literal dates - you might need to adapat that if your database does not support it.